# Wider argument types of overridding method in Java

Tags: java, oop, overriding

What OO principle is broken by the following code ? Not Java OO principle but general OO principle.

```
class GeneralArg{}
class Arg extends GeneralArg{}

class A{
    public void test(Arg a){}
}

class B extends A{
    @Override
    public void test(GeneralArg a){}
}
```

I think this should work!

However there is a compile error saying that `B.test()` doesn't override `A.test()`

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is not overriding but overloading.

You overload a method when you change the parameter list. 
You override a method when you change it implementation.

```
    public class Foo {

       public void method1() {        
       }

       public void method1(String str) {
       //We overload method1
       }

    }

    public class Bar extends Foo {

       public void method1(String str) {
           // We override method1 here
       }

       public void method1(Number num) {
           // We overload method1 here 
       }
  }
```

Note, that annotation is not mandatory it only inform the compiler that you have override some method to prevent potential faults.

Concluding when you in child class declare method with the same [signature] you override it, when you add/remove switch parameter order you overload. This rule obey to Java world as every not final method is virtual an can be overridden.

Comment: Without the @Override, would the compile not complain about ambiguity, though? (so not a valid overloading either)

Comment: Its depend on the compiler and its settings but by default from Oracle no warning should be raised.

Answer (score 2):

> Statement 1: Every GeneralArg is not an Arg.

Base definition of test says: *`test()` takes an `Arg` as input.*

B's definition says: *the same `test()` should take `GeneralArg` as input. But given Statement 1, this is can't be true.*

@Override says that you are overriding the base class's definition.

In summary, `A.test()` and `B.test()` are not same methods(`different signatures`) and hence one cannot override another.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please don't [approve suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2763764) using backticks for emphasis, but reject or improve them - see e.g. [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7437/88) why

Comment: Noted. Appreciate the tip.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a violation of any OO principle. It just changes the method signature, which is the exactly the one thing a method is identified by. Thus, the compiler does not realize that your intention is to widen the argument type of the super-method.

The [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_Substitution_Principle) allows what you want to do, Java just doesn't support it this way.

Answer (score 1):

**No, it should not!**

By annotating method with `Override` you say it overrides something but it does not.

In Java, methods are resolved and bound at the compile time. This means that declared type of argument is checked and one method is chosen. Inheritance of argument types is not important at this point.