# Specializing method arguments in subclasses in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism

Consider the following situation:

```
public abstract class AnimalFeed{
}
public class FishFeed extends AnimalFeed{
}
public class BirdFeed extends AnimalFeed{
}

public abstract class Animal{

public void eat(AnimalFeed somethingToEat)

}
```

Now I would like to define a class "Bird" extending "Animal" being sure that when the bird eats, it eats only BirdFeed.

One solution would be to specify a sort of contract, in which the caller of "eat" must pass an instance of the appropriate feed

```
public class Bird extends Animal{

@Override 
public void eat(AnimalFeed somethingToEat){

    BirdFeed somethingGoodForABird

    if(somethingToEat.instanceOf(BirdFeed)){
    somethingGoodForABird = (BirdFeed) somethingGoodForABird
    }else{
    //throws error, complaining the caller didn't feed the bird properly
    }
}
}
```

Is it acceptable to delegate the responsibility of the parameter to the caller? How to force the caller to pass a specialization of the parameter? Are there alternative design solutions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'd need to add a type variable to the class:

```
public abstract class Animal<F extends AnimalFeed> {
  public abstract void eat(F somethingToEat);
}
```

Then you can declare your subclasses as wanting a particular type of `AnimalFeed`:

```
public class Bird extends Animal<BirdFeed> {
  public void eat(BirdFeed somethingToEat) {}
}

public class Fish extends Animal<FishFeed> {
  public void eat(FishFeed somethingToEat) {}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking for doesn't make sense from an *theoretical* point of view.

*Restricting* a method parameter violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

The idea there: any occurance (*usage*) of some *base* class object must be able to deal with some *sub* class object, too.

A more simple example: when your *base* interface goes:

```
void foo(Number n)
```

then you **must not** do

```
@Override
void foo(Integer i)
```

in a subclass. Because all of a sudden, a caller

```
someObject.foo(someNumber)
```

would run into ugly ugly problems when someObject is of that derived class; which only accepts Integers, but not Numbers.

In other words: good OO design is much more than just writting down `A extends B`. You have to follow such rules; or you end up with systems are already broken on a *conceptual* point!

And for the record: it is *theoretically* valid to **widen** method parameters (in general, but in Java); and it is also ok to **restrict** the return types of methods (because these changes can **not** break client code; and that even works in Java).

Long story short: the answer here is too change your design; for example by using Generics and dependent interfaces to somehow create a relationship between the Animal and the Feed class hierarchy.

Comment: "it is very much valid to widen method parameters" In general, but not in Java: you can't widen parameter types because of the way that Java method resolution and overloading works. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337056/wider-argument-types-of-overridding-method-in-java (although I'm sure there are better Qs and As than that).

Comment: I agree that wider parameters doesn't violate LSP. I'm just saying that wider arguments aren't supported in java (whereas narrower return types are; return type isn't part of the method signature used to determine which method to invoke).

Comment: Got it; updated my answer. Although I am wondering why your answers seems to fly six times better than mine ;-)

Comment: An example that the user could directly relate and use with no or little modifications make them _fly_ better :)