# Method compiles and works with wrong type of variable passed

Tags: java, interface, extend

So here is part of code that I'm testing:

```
interface sample
{
    Vector Sum(Vector vec);
    Vector Subtraction(Vector vec);
    int Product(Vector vec);
    boolean Compare(Vector vec);
    String ToString();
}

abstract class Vector implements sample
{       
     int[] coordinates; 
     public Vector (int[] coordinates)
     {
         this.coordinates=coordinates;
     }
}

abstract Vector resVec();

public boolean Compare(Vector vec)
{
    if (this.coordinates.length == vec.coordinates.length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<vec.coordinates.length; i++)
        {
            if (this.coordinates[i] == vec.coordinates[i])
                continue;
            else return false;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        throw new ArithmeticException("Can't compare vectors of different length");
    }
    return true;
}
```

And here is classes that I call methods from: 
1)

```
class Vector3D extends Vector
{

public Vector3D(int n1,int n2,int n3) 
{
    super(new int[]{n1,n2,n3});
}
public Vector3D resVec()
{
    Vector3D resVec = new Vector3D(0,0,0);
    return resVec;
}

public boolean Compare(Vector3D vec)
{
    return super.Compare(vec);
}
```

2)

```
class VectorND extends Vector
{
    public VectorND(int...n) 
    {       
            super(n);
    }
    public VectorND resVec()
    {
        VectorND resVec = new VectorND();
        return resVec;
    }

    public boolean Compare(VectorND vec)
      {
          return super.Compare(vec);
      }
}
```

So the problem is that for some reason if I write something like this in main:

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Vector3D B = new Vector3D(1,-3,3);
        VectorND A = new VectorND(1,-3,3);
        System.out.println(A.Compare(B));
    }
}
```

It perfectly works and returns true while it should've written an exception that VectorND was expected at the call of Compare from A. What could be the problem?

Comment: you should mark a method with `@Override` if it is intended to override a method of its superclass: `@Override public boolean Compare(VectorND vec)...`

Comment: Both vectors have been passed an array of the same size (3), so they _are_ the same size, right?

Comment: Why are you expecting an exception?

Comment: With the following code you are setting Vector.coordinates                       
  Vector3D B = new Vector3D(1,-3,3);                                                                                    Then you are passing to Vector.compare which compares the same arrays

Comment: also have a look at the [java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) and add the `@Override` - it should show what the problem is

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger error in code appears if I add Override : The method Compare(VectorND) of type VectorND must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: Both Vector3D and VectorND have a common parent class Vector which itself is also defining method Compare as well as instance variable int[] coordinates hence the code gets executed just fine normally and returns the output comparing both array values which are same hence true.

Comment: @shmosel because I pass wrong variable type in method, its like I would pass an int in method that expects string or something like that

Comment: hint: `Compare(Vector a)` is not the same method as `Compare(Vector3D a)`! That means, the later one is **not** overriding the first. So `VectorND` ends with both (distinct) methods, ergo, you are explicitly calling the `Compare` from `Vector`. `@Override`  just show the compiler that you want to override the method and it gives an error if you are not doing it.

Comment: If you carefully see, the argument Compare method takes is Vector and Vector3D as well as VectorND both extend Vector class hence it accepts and method executes normally. I don't see why it should throw exception of any kind

Comment: it kind of is a hard to find mistake, that is why probably the `@Override` annotation was added

Comment: Exactly. public boolean Compare(VectorND vec) is not overriding public boolean Compare(Vector vec) as arguments different and no use of override is hiding the culplrit and as rightly said by Carlos is why override came into existence

Comment: Can be a good interview question :)

Comment: @Mak, so actually you're not expecting an _exception_ but instead a _compile-time error_? These are entirely different things.

Comment: @mickmnemonic maybe, I'm a beginner so I don't really see difference. I'm just trying to figure out what I should do to get an error with call like this.

Comment: You should really follow the Java Naming Conventions: class names start with uppercase; method and variable names with lower case. Also, `if` and `else` statements should use braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not overriding the `Compare()` method of the base class `Vector` in `VectorND` and `Vector3D`. Instead, you're declaring new methods that take an object of the same type (`VectorND` or `Vector3D`) in your subclasses. The original `Compare()` method of the base class is still available in the subclasses, and it's that method that get's called when you call `A.Compare(B)`.

To make it more clear, you have

```
Vector{
    public boolean Compare(Vector vec){ ... }
}

class Vector3D extends Vector {
    public boolean Compare(Vector vec){ ... }
    public boolean Compare(Vector3D vec){ ... } 
}

class VectorND extends Vector {
    public boolean Compare(Vector vec){ ... }
    public boolean Compare(VectorND vec){ ... } 
}
```

So when you call

```
A.Compare(B)
```

and there is no `Compare(Vector3D)` declared in class `VectorND`, what you're really doing is calling

```
Vector.Compare(Vector)
```

since both `A` and `B` are derived from the base class `Vector`.

If you really want to override the `Compare` method in `Vector` with the ones in your subclasses, you need to declare them identically in the subclasses (i.e. with the same type of parameter).

And if you **really** want the method to throw an exception in the specified case, you need to explicitly check the type of the `Vector` by using the `instanceof` operator, and throw an exception if it's not the same type.

```
public class Vector3D extends Vector {
    @Override
    public boolean Compare(Vector vec){
        if( !(vec instanceof Vector3D) )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Vector3D can only be compared to Vector3D!");

        // Compare and return true or false
    }
}
```

The `@Override` annotation indicates that you intended to override a method in the base class. If there is no matching method in the base class, for example if you try to do

```
@Override
public boolean Compare(Vector3D vec)
```

the compiler/IDE will issue an error to notify you that you're not overriding anything (since the `Vector` class has no `Compare(Vector3D vec)` method).

Comment: if I add Override I get a code error: The method Compare(VectorND) of type VectorND must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: Thanks for previous answer! And is there any way to get a compile error not a runtime one?

Comment: @Mak You could use generics, an example can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808248/specializing-method-arguments-in-subclasses-in-java