# Using generics in abstact class that implements interface

Tags: java, generics

I haven't worked with generics yet so I'm not sure how to use them in my situation. What I'm trying to achieve is to create a superclass Vector that would use generics in it and then 3 subclasses where generics type will be set as one of dimensions. Here is what I have right now:

```
interface sample {
    Vector sum(Vector vec);

    Vector subtraction(Vector vec);

    int product(Vector vec);

    boolean compare(Vector vec);

    String ToString();
}

abstract class Vector implements sample {
    int[] coordinates;

    public Vector(int[] coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    abstract Vector resVec();

    public Vector sum(Vector vec) {
        Vector result = resVec();
        if (this.coordinates.length == vec.coordinates.length) {
            for (int i = 0; i < vec.coordinates.length; i++) {
                result.coordinates[i] = this.coordinates[i] + vec.coordinates[i];
            }
        } else {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Can't sum vectors of different length");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and two subclasses for example: 
1)

```
class Vector3D extends Vector {

    public Vector3D(int n1, int n2, int n3) {
        super(new int[]{n1, n2, n3});
    }

    public Vector3D resVec() {
        Vector3D resVec = new Vector3D(0, 0, 0);
        return resVec;
    }

    public Vector3D sum(Vector vec) {
        return (Vector3D) super.sum(vec);
    }
```

2)

```
class Vector5D extends Vector {
    public Vector5D(int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5) {
        super(new int[]{n1, n2, n3, n4, n5});
    }

    public Vector5D resVec() {
        Vector5D resVec = new Vector5D(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        return resVec;
    }

    public Vector5D sum(Vector vec) {
        return (Vector5D) super.sum(vec);
    }
```

So what I want to get as a result is for example if I type in main something like this: Vector3D vec1 = new Vector3D(1,2,3); Vector5D vec2 = new Vector5D(1,2,3,4,5); and use A.sum(B); I should get a compile error because of wrong type of variable has been passed to sum method. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest using a different name to a common buitin class to avoid confusion.

Comment: I suggest you use the code formatter in your IDE, and start your classes and interface with an upper case letter.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the responsibility of the type hierarchy; that's the responsibility of the concrete class.

The big thing here is that your `sum` method is accepting a type of `Vector`, and the implementors of that `sum` method should know what is and is not a valid type that they can perform against.  Adding an `instanceof` check to your `sum` method should be all you realistically need.

Generics would help if you wanted to ensure type homogeneity across a collection of vectors, but I don't see it being of much value in this case when you know for a fact what each vector is capable of operating on.

Comment: instanceof check would only say if vector is vector3d or not and then I could throw exception which is a runtime error when I need a compile error

Comment: Yes, but the interface is clearly prescribing the method.  This indicates to me (at least) that the responsibility for determining compatibility comes at runtime for the implementor.

Comment: I'm looking for something like this but with abstract class that implements interface.  I cant quiet figure out how to use it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808248/specializing-method-arguments-in-subclasses-in-java